# Disable the button After ajax load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.php page

```
echo"<div id='div_com'></div>";
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var time= setInterval(function(){
   $("#div_com").load('showingthis.php')
   },1000);
 )};

</script>
```

showingthis.php

```
echo " <div id='divtextarea'><button id='reply_reply'type='button'>Reply</button></div>";
```

how to disable this button??after call ajax load();

Comment: `$('#reply_reply').prop('disabled', true);` ?

Comment: i use this 
$('#div_com').on('click','#divtextarea', function (event) { $('#reply_reply').prop('disabled', true); }); not workin..but working if the div is clicked :3 i want it after called it is disabled :(

Comment: So you want this to happen in a click event?  What isn't working?

Comment: i want this not on click..i want to disable the button when called...=)

Comment: The answer below shows exactly how to do that.

Comment: :( not working huhu

Comment: if it's not working then you need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem. Is this button inside a form?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  The answer literally gives you the exact code.  It couldn't be any more helpful.

Comment: men i get it !simple html disabled in a tag that i called and thats it! sorry men such a novice me..

Answer (score 0):

[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has a complete callback argument available

```
var time= setInterval(function(){
   $("#div_com").load('showingthis.php', function(){
       // new html has loaded
       $('#reply_reply').prop('disabled', true);
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: $('#div_com').on('click','#divtextarea', function (event) {
$('.reply_reply').prop('disabled', true);  
 });

Comment: it works when i use click...but i dont want to click before t will be disabled..i want it disabled after it called..:(

Comment: I'm confused. You asked for after `load()`. Not clear what you are trying to say now

Comment: sorry ... i want to disable the button when load() has been done...or disable it when t is called..

Comment: well it's the same simple call to disable wherever you do it

Comment: i get it men i disabled it in html tag button huhu i worked overnight for this i just waste time with this men. but still thank you !! good job helping us novice =)